# Can not deserialize instance with jackson

Tags: java, extjs, serialization, jackson

I'm working on a **RESTful** app in which the response is passed as JSON string from Extjs to the java , so I am using the jackson to deserialize into the java POJO.

Below is my request:

```
{
  "filter": "[{"type":"string","value":"sdadsadsa","field":"groupName"}]",
  "limit": 10
}
```

The FilterParams class looks like this:

```
class FilterParams {

    @JsonProperty( value = "type" )
    private String type;

    /** The value. */
    @JsonProperty( value = "value" )
    private String value; 

    /** The group name. */
    @JsonProperty( value = "field" )
    private String field;
}
```

For conversion to pojo am using below code

```
mapper.readValue(json, FilterParams.Class);
```

But still am getting the "**Can not deserialize instance of FilterParams**" . How to convert it into the pojo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What class has a list of `FilterParams` and a numeric value called `limit`? That's the class you need to be deserializing to in the `mapper.readValue(json, ?.class);` The only part of your json that maps to a FilterParams class is `{"type":"string","value":"sdadsadsa","field":"groupName"}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your JSON is invalid. Value of `filter` shouldn't start with `"` if it's a JSON array, or should have escaped inner `"` if it's a `String`.
2. Your `FilterParams` class does not reflect the data in your JSON at all: it should have a `limit` `int` property and an `array` or a `Collection` of `Filter`s
3. Then you should have a `Filter` class with `type`, `value` and `field` properties

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains 2 elements : filter & limits so that Jackson is not able to match this JSON String into a FilterParams object.

To ignore the JSON part that deal with limit, do the following :

```
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(<JSON_STRING>);
FilterParams fp = mapper.treeToValue(tree.get("filter"), FilterParams.class);
```